Ether stuck in smart contract
I have a smart contract which can hold ETH.
receive() external payable whenNotPaused {
    if (msg.value == 0) revert AmountZero();
    emit EthDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

function withdraw(uint256 amount) external onlyOwner nonReentrant whenNotPaused {
    if (amount == 0) revert AmountZero();
    if (address(this).balance < amount) {
        revert InsufficientBalance(amount, address(this).balance);
    }
    (bool success, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: amount}("");
    if (!success) revert TransferFailed();
    emit EthWithdrawal(owner(), amount);
}

I am able to send eth to the smart contract successfully (via Metamask for example).
When I try to call withdraw, the transaction succeeds (with any amount, even if it exceeds the amount sent to it) but the amount of eth in the smart contract doesn't change.
I have checked the blockexplorer and the arguments that are passed to withdraw are correct but is says the value is 0, for example:
Value:    0 ETH
Function called:  withdraw(uint256 amount = 20)
Gas Price:    1.599151031 Gwei
I am using Scaffold-Eth 2 to interact with my smart contract.

I wasn't specifying the correct number of decimals.
For example if I wanted to withdraw 2 ETH:
Correct: 2_000_000_000_000_000_000
Incorrect: 2

the only solution is you should get you wallet synchronized on the decentralized manual DApp network so it can safeguard your wallet from being compromised and as well help you restore all DApps data bugs you might be experiencing such high gas fees and swapping error or missing transactions
